# Changing the Add To Cart button text in WooCommerce for items with variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I'm running WooCommerce version 2.5.5. The following lines of code don't seem to change the Add To Cart button text on my product page for an item with variations:

```
add_filter('variable_add_to_cart_text', 'my_custom_cart_button_text');

function my_custom_cart_button_text() {

        return __('Buy Now', 'woocommerce');

}
```

Would you happen to know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 8):

The correct filter for the single product page is [`woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L586).

```
function my_custom_cart_button_text( $text, $product ) {
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
        $text = __('Buy Now', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'my_custom_cart_button_text', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the upvotes. It was a little too much code for a comment, but you're revised answer is very detailed and I'll upvote it too.

Answer (score 5):

> **Update:** for WooCommerce 3+

You are using an obsolete hook for prior versions 2.1 of WooCommerce *(see at the bottom the [**reference**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/))*.

First you can target the desired **product type** in those *(new)* hooks with conditions:

```php
global $product;

if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) // for simple product
    // Your text for simple product

if ($product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) // for variable product
    // Your text for variable product

if ($product->is_type( 'grouped' ) ) // for grouped product
    // Your text for grouped product

if ($product->is_type( 'external' ) ) // for external product
    // Your text for external product
```

Now you have **2 available hooks for Woocommerce**:

- One for **single product pages** (targeting the **product types** with conditions):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'my_custom_cart_button_text', 10, 2 );
```

- And the other for **product archives pages** (targeting the **product types** with conditions):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'my_custom_cart_button_text', 10, 2 );
```

And you will use one or both of them with your customized function targeting through the **variables** product type condition, this way:

```
function my_custom_cart_button_text( $button_text, $product ) {

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) )
        $button_text = __('Buy Now', 'woocommerce');

    return $button_text
}
```

---

You can also have a custom button text by product type: [**See here**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/#section-3).

---

Reference: [Change add to cart button text](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/)

Comment: I don't think those filters with the product type in the filter name exist. Can you point me to them?

Comment: Excellent answer, works smoothly in 2020.07, thank you man, best wishes!